# How do I concatenate dictionary values into one list?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of tokenised sentences much like this example below:

```
dict1 = {key1: [["first", "sentence"], ["second", "sentence"]], 
         key2: [["dog", "in", "a", "park"], ["Batman", "is", "scary"]]}
```

I want to concatenate every word in the dictionary into one single list.

```
list1 = ["first", "sentence", "second", "sentence", "dog", "in" "a", "park", "Batman", "is", 
         "scary"]
```

I have tried to do write this code, but it returned a ValueError:

```
all_words = ", ".join(((word for word in sentence) for sentence in dict1[key]) for key in dict1.keys())

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, generator found
```

How can I improve my code so that it does what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have doubly nested list, one approach is to use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

dict1 = {"key1": [["first", "sentence"], ["second", "sentence"]],
         "key2": [["dog", "in", "a", "park"], ["Batman", "is", "scary"]]}


res = list(chain.from_iterable(chain(*dict1.values())))
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['first', 'sentence', 'second', 'sentence', 'dog', 'in', 'a', 'park', 'Batman', 'is', 'scary']
```

Alternative, without `itertools.chain`:

```
res = [vi for vs in dict1.values() for v in vs for vi in v]
print(res)
```

Comment: @DaniMesejo no simpler way to do that without using `itertools`?

Comment: @BSP Added an alternative without using itertools

Comment: @BSP Why do you want to not use `itertools`? It is in python core and it is optimized.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach `itertools` module has a functional flavour that is probably not the most "pythonic" way to work. Alternatives based on list comprehension are easier to understand. You don't need to know how `chain` and `chain.from_iterable` work.

Answer (score 1):

You got the placement of for loops wrong. The first for loop should be the one  which should be parsed first and so on.

```
", ".join(word for key in dict1.keys() for sentence in dict1[key] for word in sentence  )
```